# Django/Python code: readable vs fast code

Tags: python, django

Lets say I want to get a record that match a value and I have 2 approaches to do it:

First:

```
try:
  obj = Model.objects.get(field = value)
except
  pass
```

Second:

```
if Model.objects.filter(field = value).count() > 0:
  obj = Model.objects.filter(field_value)[0]
```

Lets put the code comments aside,which way should I use or which one do you prefer to read? The first one seems faster because only 1 DB look up, but the second way seems a bit more readable, but requires 2 DB look ups.

Comment: Use get() instead of filter() if you only want a single object

Comment: [This doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/optimization/#don-t-overuse-count-and-exists) might be relevant.

Comment: Also, are you sure filter throws an exception? You might not need that try/except.

Comment: at the end of the statement I am trying to get the first record, it will throw out of index exception

Comment: @NoPyGod, the filter won't throw an exception but the [0] that accesses the first result of the queryset for assignment will.

Comment: You should `except IndexError:`, so as to not hide any of the multitude of other errors that you could get there.

Comment: I really can't say I think the latter example is more readable by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @Lattyware NoPyGod is the victim of first approach (see above comments), things are not as clear as second approach

Comment: @JamesLin NoPyGod's only confusion was with the second method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first is preferred in Python, based on the **EAFP** design principle ("Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission").  Aside from speed, one advantage of this system is that there is no race condition -- in the second example, if other concurrent access to the database changes the results between the execution of the first and the second line of code, then your results will be inconsistent.

Depending on your use of transactions, the race condition possibility may be a non-issue, but in general **EAFP** is a prominent design pattern in Python and experienced Python coders will not have any trouble reading code in that form.

ETA:  Oh, and I forgot: don't use `except:` (you do need the colon).  Use `except IndexError:` or whatever other specific exception you are looking for.  That way if you get a totally unexpected error like a failure to reach the database, it will propagate through and not be hidden.  You don't want a situation where you later write code counting on the exception being thrown to mean "there are no results" and instead the system is trying to tell you "the database is down".

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
matches = Model.objects.filter(field=value)[:1]
obj = matches[0] if matches else None
```

The query will only be evaluated once (when evaluating `matches` in the `if` part of the conditional expression), and this is used both for the emptiness check and retrieving the result. Note the slicing to limit the number of returned objects.